# Working with Sqlite.dll error

Tags: c#, sqlite

I am trying to make a small application, working with SQLite. However I am running into problems whose solutions on the Net are horribly outdated and nothing I tried works, currently I feel like I have no idea what I am doing.

**My problem:**

> Can't add a reference to SQLite.dll "A reference to sqlite3.dll could not be added. Please make sure that the file is accessible, and that it is a valid assembly or COM component."

**What I've tried:**
As far as I know in order to use SQLite in C# code I need to add a reference to an *SQLite.dll*. I went to the [Downloads](https://www.sqlite.org/download.html) page of SQLite and downloaded precompiled binaries for Windows (mainly because I have no idea what any of those things are). That didn't work, searched on the 'Net:

- Tried both the x32 and x64 version
- Installed "SQLite for Windows Runtime" extension
- Installed SQLite tools, included them in PATH variable

The only *.dll I could get going was from a [Codeproject example](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22165/Using-SQLite-in-your-C-Application) which had a *sqliteNet.dll* file (I have no idea from where) but that had other problems.

From what I looked for all the information/questions/tutorials about SQLite on the Net are horribly outdated and are no help to me.

Currently I am literally lost and have NO idea why it doesn't work and what I should do, please someone help me!

Comment: you should use a nugget package whenever it's possible, and avoid to load dll manually. like this one : https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.SQLite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you haven't tried this method then you have to test it.

- Right Click on your Project
- Click on *Manage NuGet Packages..*
- In **Browse** tab search *System.Data.SQLite* & select it
- On Right side click on <kbd>Install</kbd> button
- After installing you can use it

Answer (score 1):

can you use the nuget package for sqlite **"System.Data.SQLite"**?

Since you need a wrapper to the `c-dll` you should try some nuget package that wraps it already.